# xinput is firing touchpad events randomly, thus preventing me from clicking and moving the touchpad

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, touchpad, xinput, libinput

I just fresh installed Kubuntu but I have this very annoying problem that, out of the blue, make it so that a lot of touchpad events get randomly triggered (pressed and released) and in that timespan I cannot do anything, meaning that I cannot even move the mouse because it doesn't do anything, I guess because there are all these events that needs to be handled in the meantime.

Some context:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pc 6.5.0-10-generic #10-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 13 13:49:38 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:        23.10
Codename:       mantic
```

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0AB2:00 27C6:0D43 Mouse               id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0AB2:00 27C6:0D43 Touchpad            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Privacy Driver                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It's the touchpad, so `id=9`. Let's see the events by filtering out the motion events:

```
$ xinput test 9|grep -v motion
button press   1 
button release 1 
button press   3 
button release 3 
button press   1 
button release 1 
button press   5 
button release 5 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   6 
button release 6 
button press   6 
button release 6 
button press   6 
button release 6 
button press   5 
button release 5 
button press   6 
button release 6 
button press   5 
button release 5 
button press   5 
button release 5 
button press   5 
button release 5 
button press   5 
button release 5 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   4 
button release 4 
button press   7 
button release 7 
button press   4 
button release 4 
button press   4 
button release 4 
button press   6 
button release 6 
button press   6 
button release 6 
^C
```

Event 1 (left click) and event 2 (right click) have been triggered by me.
All the other events (4, 5, 6, 7) have been triggered automatically while I was simply moving the touchpad.

If it may be useful, I will attach the props list

```
$ xinput list-props 9
Device 'DELL0AB2:00 27C6:0D43 Touchpad':
        Device Enabled (178):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (180): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Tapping Enabled (336): 1
        libinput Tapping Enabled Default (337): 0
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (338):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (339):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (340):       0
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (341):       0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (342):  1, 0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (343):  1, 0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (309):       1
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (310):       0
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (344):    1
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (345):    1
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (311):        1, 1, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (312):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (313):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Click Methods Available (346): 1, 1
        libinput Click Method Enabled (347):    1, 0
        libinput Click Method Enabled Default (348):    1, 0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (349):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (350):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (318):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (319):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Profiles Available (320):        1, 1, 1
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled (321):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (322):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Accel Custom Fallback Points (323):    <no items>
        libinput Accel Custom Fallback Step (324):      0.000000
        libinput Accel Custom Motion Points (325):      <no items>
        libinput Accel Custom Motion Step (326):        0.000000
        libinput Accel Custom Scroll Points (327):      <no items>
        libinput Accel Custom Scroll Step (328):        0.000000
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (329):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (330):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (294):     1, 1
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (295):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (296):        0, 0
        Device Node (297):      "/dev/input/event10"
        Device Product ID (298):        10182, 3395
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (331):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (332):       1
        libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (333):        15
        libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (334):        15
        libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (335):    1
```

Please help me solve it. I really cannot do anything because it's so unpredictable and the mouse stops all the time!